# How to create constructor for a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

```
import java.util.*;

class A {

    protected int n;

    public A(int a) {
        n = a;
    }

    protected int disp() {
        return n;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    // what should i do here
}

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code Here
        int a =5;
        A obj= new B(a);
        System.out.print(obj.disp());
    }
}
```

Comment: `public B(A a)`? you should also think carefully if you really want `B` to hold an instance of its parent class, it's usually unnecessary.

Comment: Since you in order to `extend class A`, you would have to ideally initialize `Object A` so create a constructor which calls `new B(int a){ this.super(a);}`

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni the `this` is superfluous. a `super(a)` suffices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is important is that `A` is initialized using one of its consutructors. It is **not necessary** that the constructor in child class `B` match the parameters of the constructor(s) in `A`. Hence, you may define any constructor in the child class `B` but make sure that you call `super( <some int> )` in that.

Eg, even the following is fine.

```
class B extends A {
    public B(){ //Default constructor
        super( 1 );
    }
}
```

Also,

1. If you have more than one constructor in child class `B`, then each of them must call `super( <some int> )`.
2. If you have more than one constructor in parent class `A`, then in the child class constructor, calling any one of them through `super( <params> )` will do.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following in `B` class:

```
class B extends A {
  public B(final int a) {
    super(a);
  }
}
```

What happen here is that we're calling the constructor of our parent (`A`)